# Copy file code?

Tags: c#

I need a copy file on folder to another folder and i'm use this

```
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
                string xx = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
                string yy = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                File.Copy(xx, yy);
```

But is not working.
Why?

Comment: Because you are using a folderbrowser and not a filebrowser, you're not copying files

Comment: What exaclty does "not working" mean? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: May we have little information on xx and yy? So it will be obvious what File.Copy is trying to do.

Comment: "it is not working" is ***never*** an acceptable problem description.  Not on stackoverflow, not anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

I assume you want to read a file then write it to new one.

Hope it helps.

```
string sourceFile;
string newFile = "C:\NewFile\NewFile.txt";
string fileToRead = "C:\ReadFile\ReadFile.txt";
bool overwriteExistingFile = true; //change to false if you want no to overwrite the existing file.

bool isReadSuccess = getDataFromFile(fileToRead, ref sourceFile); 

if (isReadSuccess)
{
    File.Copy(sourceFile, newFile, overwriteExistingFile);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occured :" + sourceFile);
}



//Reader Method you can use this or modify it depending on your needs.
public static bool getDataFromFile(string FileToRead, ref string readMessage)
{
    try
    {
        readMessage = "";
        if (!File.Exists(FileToRead))
        {
            readMessage = "File not found: " + FileToRead;
            return false;
        }
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(FileToRead))
        {
            readMessage = r.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        readMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not use filenames in your source code.
I made an example. File copy function.

```
    public void SaveStockInfoToAnotherFile(string sPath, string dPath, string filename)
    {
        string sourcePath = sPath;
        string destinationPath = dPath;
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
        string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, filename);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    //string xx = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

    //folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    //string yy = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    //foreach (string file in files)
    //{
    //    File.Copy(xx + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file), yy + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));
```